# How to specify different log4j.properties file for multiple spark applications in same project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j

My project have multiple spark applications (each with its own spark session) and all of them refers to same log4j.properties file. I want to specify different log4j.properties file (log4j_1.properties) for some of the jobs. I tried below but it is still taking configuration from original file (log4j.properties) only.

Not sure what I am missing here?

```
conf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j_1.properties")
```

Note:

1. I can see above option set on SparkUI environment tab
2. Both log4j_1.properties and log4j.properties are there in classpath

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_1.properties
```

Comment: Thanks. I realised that setting this option doesn't work in client mode. I forgot to mention that my code is running on local and not on cluster. Now, I will try specifying just the file name as you suggested and run on server.